# change counter c program not displaying correct output

Tags: c

I am working on a change counter program and I am stuck, I have searched here and 2 other coding forums, google and youtube, but haven't found an answer yet...my program sucks and i am brand new to c/c++...my txt book is not here yet so I am trying to read every every thing i can get my hands on till it gets here

This is what the output should be in the console window:

```
Welcome to Change Counter by Jo Mama!!
Please enter the total amount of purchase: $52.173
$52.173
Please enter amount of money tendered: $60
$60.00
Your change is: $7.83
-------------------------------------------
Twenties : 0
Tens : 0
Fives : 1
Ones : 2
Quarters : 3
Dimes : 0
Nickels : 1
Pennies : 3
-------------------------------------------
Thank you for using Change Counter!
```

here is what i have so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
// define variables here
long double numberOfTwenties = 0;
long double numberOfTens = 0;
long double numberOfFives = 0;
long double numberOfOnes = 0;
long double numberOfQuarters = 0;
long double numberOfDimes = 0;
long double numberOfNickels = 0;
long double numberOfPennies = 0;
double purchasePrice = 0;
double amountTendered = 0;
double amountOfChange = 0;
double amountOfChangeCents = 0;

// start program here
printf("Welcome to the change counter by Josh Manion!!\n\n");
printf("Please enter the total amount of purchase: $");
scanf("%d", &purchasePrice);
printf("%d\n", purchasePrice);
printf("Please enter amount of money tendered: $");
scanf("%d", &amountTendered);
printf("%d\n", amountTendered);

//do change calculations here
amountOfChange = (amountTendered - purchasePrice);
printf("Your change is: $%d\n", amountOfChange);

numberOfTwenties = amountOfChange / 20;
//amountOfChange = numberOfTwenties %= amountOfChange;
numberOfTens = (amountOfChange / 10);
numberOfFives = (amountOfChange / 5);
numberOfOnes = (amountOfChange / 1);
numberOfQuarters = (amountOfChange * 0.25);

// print change calculations here


printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
//display denominations of change here
printf("Twenties: %d\n", numberOfTwenties);
printf("Tens: %d\n", numberOfTens);
printf("Fives: %d\n", numberOfFives);
printf("Ones: %d\n", numberOfOnes);
printf("Quarters: %d\n", numberOfQuarters);
printf("Dimes: %d\n", numberOfDimes);
printf("Nickels: %d\n", numberOfNickels);
printf("Pennies: %d\n", numberOfPennies);

printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Thank you for using the Change Counter!");

getchar();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is that my program doesn't work, it shows the change after the prompt but not the breakdown of denominations, I am sposed to use the "%" to bring down the change amount, but i havent found any examples. I don't know what else to say... besides I'm new and this post will help a lot of people...

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behaviour : you must use `%Lf` as the `printf` modifier to print a `long double` (same issue with your usage of `scanf`)

Comment: cplusplus.com has a nice table for the various modifiers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @Kay I recommend the [printf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). cplusplus.com is sometimes frowned upon.

Comment: @remyabel, die.net is badly formatted and overladen with ads.